# why Jupyterhub requires root /sudo privilages to launch Jupyterlab notebooks?

Tags: jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I m trying to deploy jupyterhub on prod servers and here we dont have root /sudo permission to launch notebooks for multi user. i m trying to use sudospawner to deploy jupyterhub without root permissions and still facing issue.

followed document
https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/config-sudo.html#

can any one share config file of jupyterlab of how to use sudospawner ?

Comment: Those docs seem to me too very clearly indicate that you need to have root or sudo access to set up jupyterhub, both as a root user or using sudospawner. I think you’ll need to get help from your administrator to set this up.

Comment: The jupyter community forum on discourse is a good way to get help though if you want a second opinion: https://discourse.jupyter.org/